# Why does java.util.Stack allow .add(int, E)?

Tags: java, stack

I am making a `Deck` class in Java. I only want the top `Card` to be accessible. I'm considering making `Deck` extend `Stack`, but `Stack` inherits from `Vector`, which has a method `add(int, E)`. Why does `Stack` allow you to add an element anywhere in it? Is there a way to remove/disallow calls to this method?

On the other hand, maybe I am completely thinking about this wrong. Is there a better way to make a `Deck` class? Should I make it extend and/or implement a different class and/or interface(s)?

Answer (score 4):

I would use a Deque (also pronounced Deck)  Stack and Vector were designed almost 20 years ago and Deque is a relatively new design (about 8 years)

Stack doesn't use an interface allowing it to hide methods which don't make sense for it's intended purpose.

Comment: For completeness: [`ArrayDeque`: *This class is likely to be faster than Stack when used as a stack, and faster than LinkedList when used as a queue.*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html)

Comment: Yes, that looks like it will work _much_ better than stack haha, thanks!

Comment: @hcps-tenembasj LinkedList also implements Deque however you can hide this fact by using the Deque interface. I prefer ArrayDeque if you can specify a limited size.

Answer (score 1):

Stack is an old class, just like Vector, that shouldn't be used anymore. You can't "disable" this method because, as you pointed out, Stack extends Vector, which has this method. And a subclass extends what a superclass can do, and does not restrict it. That's the principle of polymorphism. Since a Vector can di it, and since a STack is a Vector, it can do it as well.

Consider using `Collections.asLifoQueue(new LinkedList());`

Answer (score 1):

Stack extending Vector is an example of bad design in the java libraries (see [this](http://books.google.co.il/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&pg=PA86&lpg=PA86&dq=extend%20vector%20effective%20java&source=bl&ots=yYLhLfw0MZ&sig=hC7OL1Am_NolyiBc8A0lR_xKs1o&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Rhv9UsPwE4Py7Aa_yYG4DA&ved=0CCcQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false) from effective java).

as this item suggests, i'd avoid inheriting from a container and instead use composition